# Vs Code tabbar design (Default drop shadow)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to customize my vs code theme but did not get any option to disable the drop shadow of the tab bar of the VS Code.

There is some option to modify the tab bar using the "editor
not get "editorGroupHeader.tabbar" but I am not able to find any option to disable the drop shadow.

[tabbar drop shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W9EI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have figured it out and am happy to share it here...

```
"scrollbar.shadow": "#HEX",
```

You can use this property to change the shadow and background color.